# How to implement a simple shopping cart without Commerce and Ubercart?

Tags: 7, ubercart, commerce

I need simple solution for shopping cart without big monstrous modules like a [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) or [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce). I've a small site (catalog) with a few products. I need add to each of them an <kbd>Add to cart</kbd> button, cart block and page (can be made using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)). Checkout must be just a form with few a fields (like Name, Address etc), which can be made using Webform.

Why Commerce and similar modules are not good for me: I don't need specific fields like SKU, product displays facilities, online payments, registration for user, tax calculation and other. I just want to keep it all simple.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Basic cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/basic_cart) module is the best solution for you...

> Basic cart is a very simple shopping cart / checkout process for
>   Drupal, that just sends 2 emails after each order. Along with the
>   shopping cart, this module also provides a block where you can view
>   your cart's content. It's ideal for small websites with only a few
>   products or other content types being sold, for example touristic
>   offers.

Answer (score 2):

The [Light Shop](https://www.drupal.org/project/lightshop) module is a simple and lightweight e-commerce solution which doesn't require the [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) or [Ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) modules (as in your question title).

Here is a quote from its project page:

> - Session-stored basket.
> - Adding to basket and its subsequent editing/checkout process is done using AJAX. Also it works fine when JavaScript is turned off.
> - Node based shopping. As the product can be assigned to any node type. One or more. With full support Field API features (regarding nodes).
> - Orders history. For each order will be created a separate node.
> - There is no dependence on other modules.
> - Full support for working with anonymous users
> - Integration with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

[image]

The configuration of this module (via `admin/config/lightshop`) is pretty forward:

#### 1. On the settings page you need specify:

**General Settings**:

- The site e-mail for notifications about new orders.
- Specify what node types are product.
- Optionally you may specify whether to display the graph with quantity of the product and its price (and which field will contain this value).

  [image]

**Notification Settings**:

- Check the appropriate box if notification of the created order must be sent to the customer also.
- Check the fields whose data you want to be included in the notification.

  [image]

#### 2. Choose the region for display basket block.

[image]

#### 3. On permissions page set which roles can use the basket and make purchases.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depends upon your further needs. Do you also need reports of orders placed? Which payment gateway are you going to use for checkout?

If you want it really simple, maybe you can add a paypal form. You can try this module https://www.drupal.org/project/pay

> This module can be used by other modules to collect and track
>   payments. Through this API, any module can provide a payment form and
>   payments can be handled and tracked centrally.

Comment: No, I need only simple form, which send values to admin email

Comment: Create a generic paypal form then. Using a little bit of php, you can pass the product title and price dynamically to the form.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PayPal, you can just go to their site and create a button to copy and paste (no need for a dedicated module). PayPal captures their address and email which they forward to you once the transaction is complete.

This method may be a bit more Spartan than what you intend but should get the job done without extra overhead.